# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Buenas amigos, tengo el siguiente problema:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Para no colocar todo el código, recreare el error de una manera mas corta:

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Frame().pack()
str_var = tk.StringVar()
entrada = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable= str_var).pack()
boton_destruir = tk.Button(ventana,
                           text="Destruir",
                           command=lambda:entrada.destroy()).pack(side="bottom")
```

Esto ocurre cuando quiero destruir un [entry](/questions/tagged/entry) y un [label](/questions/tagged/label), necesito saber de que forma puedo eliminarlos, ya que en el programa que desarrollo, necesito eliminarlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo métodos `pack` mételos en una línea nueva. Ahora mismo, lo que estás asignando a las variables no es el *widget* en sí.

Un ejemplo que funciona:

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Frame()
ventana.pack()
str_var = tk.StringVar()
entrada = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable= str_var)
entrada.pack()
boton_destruir = tk.Button(ventana, 
                           text="Destruir", 
                           command=lambda:entrada.destroy())
boton_destruir.pack(side="bottom")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tenias razón, :D